# How we can call a method from child with State container Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, components, blazor-webassembly

I want to call a method from a child Component and I have this code

AppState:

```
public class AppState
{
    public string MyMessage { get; private set; }
    public string MyMsgToChildren { get; private set; }


    public event Action OnChange;

    public void SetMessage(string msg)
    {
        MyMessage = msg;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }

    public void SetMessageToChildren(string msg)
    {
        MyMsgToChildren = msg;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }
    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

and Child Component #1:

```
    @inject AppState AppState
<p>============================</p>
<h3>#1 Child</h3>
<p>send from Father :<b>@AppState?.MyMsgToChildren</b>  </p>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <button @onclick="SetMessage">Send To Parent</button>

</div>
<p>============================</p>

@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        AppState.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        AppState.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
    void SetMessage()
    {
        AppState.SetMessage("Message From Child #1");
    }

}
```

and the #2 Child is the same code with #1
and I have a parent component :

```
@page "/State"

@inject AppState AppState
<p>============================</p>
<h3>Parent</h3>
<p>send from child:<b>@AppState?.MyMessage</b>  </p>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <button @onclick="SendMsgTochildren">Send To Parent</button>
</div>
<ChildComponent></ChildComponent>
<Child2Component></Child2Component>

@code {

    public string MsgToChildren { get; private set; } = "Hi, Im your father - ";
    int i = 0;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        AppState.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        AppState.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }

    void SendMsgTochildren()
    {
        i++;
        AppState.SetMessageToChildren(MsgToChildren + i.ToString());
    }

    /* I want to call this method from Child*/
    void TargetMethod(int page) 
    { 
    
    }
}
```

this app works well and just I want to call this method: "TargetMethod(int page)"
from one of my child components and I need to pass an integer parameter as well

I want to use this code for pagination. I try to make a component(pagination) and add it to each table component and the pagination will be the grandchild of the main component and I know I can use the other ways but I prefer to use state Container
to communicate between pagination and others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to call this method: "TargetMethod(int page)" from one of my
> child components and I need to pass an integer parameter as well

then you can try like this:

**AppState.cs**

```
 public class AppState
    {
        public Action<int> OnCounterChanged { get; set; }   
    }
```

**Grandparent.razor**

```
    @inject AppState AppState;
@page "/grandparent"
<h1>Counter Value from Grandparent : @Counter</h1>
    <Parent/>


@code{

    public int Counter { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        AppState.OnCounterChanged += OnCounterChanged;
    }

    private void OnCounterChanged(int counter)
    {
        Counter = counter;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

**Parent.razor**

```
@inject AppState AppState;
<h1>Counter Value from Parent : @Counter</h1>
<Child />


@code{

    public int Counter { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        AppState.OnCounterChanged += OnCounterChanged;
    }

    private void OnCounterChanged(int counter)
    {
        Counter = counter;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
<Child />
```

**Child.razor**

```
@inject AppState AppState;
<h1>Counter Value from child : @Counter</h1>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="UpdateCounter"> Update Counter</button>
@code{

    public int Counter { get; set; }

    private void UpdateCounter()
    {
        AppState.OnCounterChanged.Invoke(++Counter);
    }
}
```

I'm updating the counter from the child component and invoking the event with an `int` parameter. (it's just a demo)

Comment: it works but my code is async code and I have errors for  async override Task OnInitializedAsync()

Comment: try like this on your AppState : `public Func<int, Task> OnCounterChanged { get; set; }`. for async method it should be `Func<int, Task>` instead of `Action<int>`

Comment: it doesn't work with the main code that I have for pagination but for this code is working I add another question and add all the main code thanks

Comment: here is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111539/how-to-communicate-between-components-and-call-a-method-in-blazor-using-state-co

Answer (score 0):

Add an PagingEventArgs class.

```
    public class PagingEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Page { get; set; }
    }
```

Add an event and notifier to your AppState Class:

```
public event EventHandler<PagingEventArgs> PageChanged;

public void NotifyPageChanged(object sender, PagingEventArgs e)
    => PageChanged.Invoke(sender, e);
```

call from your paginator

```
private void Page(int page)
{
    appservice.NotifyPageChanged(this, new PagingEventArgs { Page = page });
}
```

and register for the event in where you want to consume it.